# Return Dataframe if sequence of entries meets condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a list of dataframes A, where each dataframe is constructed like so:

```
df =    'Subject ID'  'Score'
        a              20
        b              25
        c              30
        d              35
        e              40
```

Now, I would like to return another list that contains every dataframe in A such that the sequence of subject according to score is  a< b< c < d < e .  So far I've tried a few things like so:

```
for df in A:
    ascore=(df.get_value(1,1, takeable=True)))
    bscore=(df.get_value(2,2, takeable=True)))
    cscore=(df.get_value(3,3, takeable=True)))
    dscore=(df.get_value(3,3, takeable=True)))
    escore=(df.get_value(3,3, takeable=True)))
    if ascore<bscore<cscore<dscore<escore:
        newlist.append(df)
```

Is there a method that works particularly well with pandas, or should I convert the dataframes to a different object and use nested if statements?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please explain this in more depth? `Now, I would like to return another list that contains every dataframe in A such that the sequence of subject according to score is a< b< c < d < e `

Comment: Of courese!  So, basically, I want to append each item in A such that we have a monotonic sequence with respect to the ordered pairs (a, a's score), (b, b's score)....(e, e's score).  Now, I would like this monotonic sequence to be constructed in "alphabetical order", so the a pair would come first, then the b pair, etc etc.  

Our Dataframe is basically trial information and we want to collect the dataframes that are tracking improvement :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
l=[df1,df]

s=[(x['SubjectID'].rank() == x['Score'].rank()).all() for x in l ]


from itertools import compress

list(compress(l, s))

Out[1040]: 
[  SubjectID  Score
 0         a     20
 1         b     25
 2         c     30
 3         d     35
 4         e     40]
```

Data input

```
df1
Out[1041]: 
  SubjectID  Score
0         a     20
1         b     25
2         c     60
3         d     35
4         e     40

df
Out[1042]: 
  SubjectID  Score
0         a     20
1         b     25
2         c     30
3         d     35
4         e     40
```

Comment: @user7351362 yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series.is_monotonic_increasing`:

```
s = df.sort_values(by='Subject ID')['Score']
s.is_monotonic_increasing
```

Output:

```
True
```

Now, lets create some data:

```
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()
df3 = df.copy()
df2.loc[4,'Score'] = 1  #non increasing scores
df3.loc[2,'Score'] = 4  #non increasing scores

l = [df1,df2,df3]

[i for i in l if i.sort_values(by='Subject ID')['Score'].is_monotonic_increasing]
```

Output:

```
#df1 which is othe only dataframe with increasing scores
[  Subject ID  Score
 0          a     20
 1          b     25
 2          c     30
 3          d     35
 4          e     40]
```

Comment: my goodness, this is super cool too.  I will definitely be practicing this one.

Comment: @user7351362  Thanks.